# How fix ansiStyles error, while running node script with chalk lib?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run, have such kind of error, when I run chalk lib

[image: here image, how I run, and error]

I also try `node index.js` same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.